# AutoRoute navigatorKey currentState is null

Tags: flutter, navigation, auto-route

I am using auto_route for navigation. I have updated an app from the old Flutter version to Flutter 3. The app navigation works with context but I want to navigate using paths or named routes. It is not working as the navigatorKey is null and I cannot access the currentState.

What I am doing is:

```
class GlobalKeys{
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

But I am not sure where to provide this in MaterialApp.router in main file. I have tried something like the below:

```
MaterialApp.router(
      key: GlobalKeys.navigatorKey,
)
```

I get currentState as null due to which I cannot navigate

```
dynamic redirectTo(String path) async {
      navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('$path');
}
```

As another solution provided by the [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package I tried the below code also but it does nothing as in it executes the statement but nothing happens. It does not even throw any error.

```
getIt<AppRouter>().pushNamed('$path');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use navigatorKey property instead of key property. But unfortunately navigatorKey is not available in MaterialApp.router() constructor. It is available in MaterialApp() constructor.